# IBM Alert Notification service is not sending mail notifications

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have configured Alert Notification. I can see alerts generated in "Alert Viewer" and even in "My Alert" tab. But somehow I am not getting any alert message in mail or mobile number.

I think I have configured User and Group correctly by assigning work hours and notification preferences. In the manage group section also I have assigned schedule to user. Tried almost everything but still no mail notification. However I am able to get notification if I send them manually.

How can I troubleshoot the problem?

Answer (score 0):

- IF you have created a new subscription, we have enabled verification of email address and Phone number. Make sure that you have verified them before adding the user or the group to the Notification Policy.

  - From the Alert Viewer, select the Alert, you should see the history of the notification which points out who got notified and on which channel.  If you do not see the information, then check your policies.

Hope this helps.

Thanks and Regards
Sudhakar

Comment: I am following up. Please let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Hello Sudhakar, 

Thanks for your response. I am able to solve the problem. Now I am getting alerts on mail and phone. 
I have another question. Is it posible to get both SMS and Voice call for same alert? 
When I select both in user notification settings, I get only SMS and not call. 
When I remove SMS from settings. I get the voice call. 
does that mean there is some kind of default preference set in user notification settings?

Thanks again for help.